# How can I pass a String data from a list from a View to a function which is in my ViewModel in SwitUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

I have a list of `Text(String)` in my app and I would like to pass the `String` to a function in my `ViewModel: getPlayerMenuChoice` to tell `ItemDetailView` the details it will have to show according to the User choice in the list.

I wrote the code below but it does not pass the data.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MenuItemRow: View {
    let item:SpeakGame
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(viewModel.sentences, id:(\.id)) { list in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ItemDetailView(item: list.sentence[0]),label:{
                    Text(list.translation)
                        
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                         viewModel.getPlayerMenuChoice(choice: list.sentence[0].definition)

                       })
                       
                    })
}
```

Can you help me with that?

I would really appreciate.

Thank you!

Comment: This needs a [mre] and an explanation of what you're seeing that differs from what you expect.

Comment: IMHO it might help to understand the basics of SwiftUI. Could you watch https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10040

Comment: Why don't you just pass `list` to `ItemDetailView` Instead of just one of its properties. I am not sure what you are doing with the tap gesture, but it doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

List works with bindings so you can get write access to the item in a subview, e.g.

```
@EnvironmentObject var store: Store
...
List($store.sentences) { $sentence in
    NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailView(item: $sentence)
```

FYI there is no need for view model objects in SwiftUI, the View struct and property wrappers already do that job.